# Setting the :public_folder per route in Sinatra?

Tags: angularjs, sinatra

I'm in a situation where I need to serve multiple separate angularjs apps from Sinatra. Yes, these should be served from a HTTP server but that is not an option.

Here is my directory setup (stripped down for example purposes)

```
/SinatraApp
|--  public
|    |--  App1
|    |    |--  scripts
|    |    |--  styles
|    |    |--  index.html
|    |--  App2
|    |    |--  scripts
|    |    |--  styles
|    |    |--  index.html
|--  app.rb
```

I tried first

```
set :public_folder, 'public'
```

And then in each index route respectively

```
get '/App1' do
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'App1', 'index.html')
end
get '/App2' do
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'App2', 'index.html')
end
```

This doesn't work though. It serves the index.html file fine but assets link to localhost/scripts not localhost/App1/scripts. I then try setting the :public_folder setting per route. No luck.

```
get '/App1' do
  set :public_folder, File.join('public', 'App1')
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'index.html')
end
```

and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /App1
undefined method `set' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x2548ba8>
file: app.rb location: block in <main> line: 73
```

I really want to avoid spawning another Sinatra app for another angular app and I really need this to work. Thoughts?

Comment: `Yes, these should be served from a HTTP server but that is not an option` and why is not an option?

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution for this. Module Applications in Sinatra in combination of a config.ru file. http://titusd.co.uk/2010/04/07/a-beginners-sinatra-tutorial/